# Como puedo clonar un objeto de java?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Como puedo hacer una copia de un objeto o un nodo de javafx ? concretamente de la clase SubScene.

He probado con la interfaz Cloneable y también con esta librería https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning, ninguna me ha funcionado.

Hacerlo mediante un fichero fxml no es una opción.

Comment: ¿Qué has probado exactamente (código)? ¿Qué problemas te ha dado?

Comment: si utilizo Cloneable al añadir ese nodo en otro lugar desaparece del anterior y utilizando la librería sale esta excepción Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D$1$$Lambda$65.1323471897

Comment: @JavierReyeroHuerga agrega ejemplos de lo que has tratado y te ayudo, saludos.